# How to load CSS file in facelet page

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

I have the following code that charge on a master page and I need to insert a specific css for it, but does not work

```
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"    class="contenido">
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style-pago-anual.css" target="head" />
<p id="miClase">Prueba de houtputStyle</p>
<h2 class="mod2">Cobro de Recibos</h2>
<p> Bienvenido a la Pagina de Cobros</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSF has its own way to handle resources like CSS, Images and others, it's called Resource Handler. Check these links:

http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/

[What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your css file is in WebContent/css then
use this

```
<link href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/mycss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

That should load the css file

Comment: That works, but wann't to load it in a master page, I want to load it in a html loaded by AJAX.

Comment: Well you can load the html on a master page and then apply whatever style you need in the ajax div that you are trying to load. Is there any specific reason why you want to avoid your css to be loaded before ajax??